# PHP - simple shortcode parser, output order is wrong

Tags: php

I have a simple function which parse shortcode tags and its attribute,
but it has some problem in output.

Like, this is my `content` in a string with a shortcode inside it:

```
$content = 'This is lorem ispium test [gallery image="10"] and text continues...'
```

I want the result output like this:

```
This is lorem ispium test 
----------------------------------------------
|        This is output of gallery            |

-----------------------------------------------
and text continues...
```

But now shortcode is not rendering where the shortcode is called, instead of this shortcode render at the top. like:

```
    ----------------------------------------------
    |        This is output of gallery            |

    -----------------------------------------------
    This is lorem ispium test and text continues...
```

**Kindly tell how do I render shortcode where it was called**

```
function shortcode($content) {

    $shortcodes = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', get('shortcodes')));
    $pattern    = "/(.?)\[($shortcodes)(.*?)(\/)?\](?(4)|(?:(.+?)\[\/\s*\\2\s*\]))?(.?)/s";

    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this,'handleShortcode'), $content);
}

function handleShortcode($matches) {

    $prefix    = $matches[1];
    $suffix    = $matches[6];
    $shortcode = .$matches[2];

    // allow for escaping shortcodes by enclosing them in double brackets ([[shortcode]])
    if($prefix == '[' && $suffix == ']') {
        return substr($matches[0], 1, -1);
    }

    $attributes = array(); // Parse attributes into into this array.

    if(preg_match_all('/(\w+) *= *(?:([\'"])(.*?)\\2|([^ "\'>]+))/', $matches[3], $match, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach($match as $attribute) {
            if(!empty($attribute[4])) {
                $attributes[strtolower($attribute[1])] = $attribute[4];
            } elseif(!empty($attribute[3])) {
                $attributes[strtolower($attribute[1])] = $attribute[3];
            }
        }
    }
    //callback to gallery
    return $prefix. call_user_func(array($this,$shortcode), $attributes, $matches[5], $shortcode) . $suffix;
}


function gallery($att, $cont){
    //gallery output
}
```

Please note: it is not related to wordpress, it is a custom script.

Comment: I think `shortcode()` is the OP's entry point, which is supposed to `echo`...

Comment: yes @mavrosxristoforos is right

Comment: Please consider adding parts of your `gallery` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem may be in your `function gallery($att, $cont)`.
If that function uses `echo` or `print` instead of `return`, then it makes perfect sense to show up before the actual content does.

**EDIT**:
If you can't change the gallery code, then yes, you can use `output buffering`.

```
function handleShortcode($matches) {
  ...
  ob_start();
  call_user_func(array($this,$shortcode), $attributes, $matches[5], $shortcode);
  $gallery_output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  return $prefix . $gallery_output . $suffix;
}
```

Related readings:
[PHP ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
[PHP ob_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)

Comment: yes there is an echo inside a `gallery` function, I cant change it, cuz it is core function.. what to do ? can I use buffer ?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect what you can do, since the gallery function cannot be changed.

Comment: Thnaks, it was very helpful